# Нужно ли ставить запятую перед как?

Tags: пунктуация

переводится с английского языка как полный пансион

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...переводится с английского языка как "полный пансион".

Оборот не обособляется, так как указывает способ перевода (переводится как? каким образом").